# BigQuery: get median and distinct count in one query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with `identity_id`, `session_length`, and `first_dates` (unique per identity). I need to calculate median length but also count distinct `identity_id` in the table. I'm struggling to execute both queries in one.

The query below should calculate `median_length` correctly (I hope!):

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT identity_id,
  median_length,
  first_date
FROM (
  SELECT
    identity_id,
    session_length,
    first_date,
    PERCENTILE_CONT(session_length, 0.5) OVER(PARTITION BY identity_id) AS median_length
  FROM my_table)
```

But when I add to this query `COUNT(DISTINCT identity_id)` or `COUNT(1)` inside `FROM` I get errors asking to include  identity_id in `GROUP BY`. It makes total sense but when I do that I get another error complaining about median_length not being grouped or aggregated.

**Table Example**:

| identity_id | session_length | first_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23 | 01-01-2020 |
| 2 | 3 | 01-02-2020 |
| 1 | 2 | 01-01-2020 |
| 3 | 11 | 01-03-2020 |
| 4 | 22 | 01-04-2020 |
| 5 | 28 | 01-05-2020 |
| 2 | 13 | 01-02-2020 |
| 2 | 73 | 01-02-2020 |
| 3 | 29 | 01-03-2020 |

**Desired Output**:

| identity_id | median_length | first_date | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12.5 | 01-01-2020 | 2 |
| 2 | 13 | 01-02-2020 | 3 |
| 3 | 20 | 01-03-2020 | 2 |
| 4 | 22 | 01-04-2020 | 1 |
| 5 | 28 | 01-05-2020 | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below

```
create temp function median (arr any type) as (
  if(mod(array_length(arr), 2) = 0,
    ( arr[offset(div(array_length(arr), 2) - 1)] +
      arr[offset(div(array_length(arr), 2))])  / 2,
      arr[offset(div(array_length(arr), 2))] )
);
select identity_id, 
  median(array_agg(session_length order by session_length)) as median_length,
  min(first_date) as first_date, 
  count(1) as `count`
from `project.dataset.table`
group by identity_id
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
SELECT identity_id, median_length,
       MIN(first_date), COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             PERCENTILE_CONT(session_length, 0.5) OVER(PARTITION BY identity_id) AS median_length
      FROM my_table t
     ) t
GROUP BY identity_id, median_length;
```